# Trying to perform an update on reviews but i get no response

Tags: reactjs, crud

I'm trying to update a review then send it to my database but i get no response or error in the console, the delete is working well and deleting on the database.

'''
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function Renderreview() {
const [renderReview, setRenderReview] = useState([])

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('/reviews')
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            setRenderReview(res.data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
}, [])

function handleDelete(id) {
    axios.delete(`/reviews/${id}`,)
}
function handleSubmit(id){
    axios.update(`/reviews/${id}`,)
}

return (
    <div className='card1'>
        <h2>reviews</h2>
        {renderReview.map((renderReview) => {
            return (
                <div className='renderedreviews'>{renderReview.review}
                    <button
                        onClick={() => {
                            handleDelete(renderReview.id);
                        }}
                        key={renderReview.review}>
                        Delete
                    </button>


                    <form className='reviews' onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
                        <input onChange={(e)=>handleSubmit(e)} id="review" defaultvalue={renderReview.review} placeholder="edit" type="text"></input>
                        
                        <button onClick={() =>{
                            handleSubmit(renderReview.id);
                        }}
                        key ={renderReview.review}
                        >edit review</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            )
        })}
    </div>
)
```

}

export default Renderreview

'''

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you intended to use `axios.put` instead of `axios.update`, as `PUT` is the method usually used to send update requests

Comment: thank you, yes I did update it to put, but I'm getting an Axios error 404

Comment: maybe your server is running on different host or port. try giving the fully qualified domain name instead of just the path. eg. `http://localhost:5000/reviews/${id}`

Comment: i confirmed it is running on the correct server, but still no success

Comment: since delete is working i assume that the server is running and reachable. maybe you have not defined the route for updating request properly. try using postman to try and make sure the route in the server is created and reachable. i cant give any more info without knowing how your backend is setup

Comment: let me try that and also update the question to share my back end